# Quotes change after using HTMLPurifier and CKEditor

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

I am susing a script which uses CKEditor and HtmlPurifier.
It changes `<p dir="rtl">` to `<p dir="&quot;rtl&quot;">` after save.
How to prevent this?

Actually, i don't know if it is a PHP, CKEditor or HTMLPurifier problem settings.

Comment: Since the HTML Purifier demo (http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&html=%3Cp+dir%3D%22rtl%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&submit=Submit) doesn't do this, can you tell us a bit more about your setup and configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default action of CKEditor, it encodes HTML attributes.

This essentially helps prevent XSS attacks.

If you would like to avoid this(**Warning**: not safe from XSS), you could use the following PHP function to either send to database or output:

```php
htmlspecialchars_decode($variable);
```